# Can't get Pascal to work properly

Tags: pascal

What is wrong with the following code? It crashes when I enter a number.

I've spent over 2 hours trying to figure out and still can't, I learning pascal so please bear with me.

```
Program Game;

var
  PlayerOneScore: Integer;
  PlayerTwoScore: Integer;
  BallsNo: Integer;
  CurrentScore: Integer;
  Ptr: Integer;
  Result: Integer;

Begin
  CurrentScore := 0;
  PlayerOneScore:= 0;
  PlayerTwoScore:= 0;
  Writeln('How many balls do you wish to face?');
  Readln(BallsNo);
  Ptr:=BallsNo;
  While Ptr < 1 Do
  Begin
    Repeat
      Ptr:=Ptr+1;
      CurrentScore:=0;
      Writeln ('Player turn');
      Writeln ('Please roll the bowling die');
      Writeln ('Enter 1 if result is a 1');
      Writeln ('Enter 2 if result is a 2');
      Writeln ('Enter 3 if result is a 4');
      Writeln ('Enter 4 if result is a 6');
      Writeln ('Enter 5 if result is a 0');
      While BallsNo >0 Do
      Begin
        Repeat
          Writeln('This is',BallsNo);
          Readln(Result);
          BallsNo:=BallsNo-1;
        Until BallsNo = 0;
        If Result = 1 Then
          CurrentScore:= CurrentScore+1
        Else If Result = 2 THEN
          CurrentScore:= CurrentScore+2
        Else If Result = 3 THEN
          CurrentScore:= CurrentScore+4
        Else If Result = 4 THEN
          CurrentScore := CurrentScore+6
      End;
    Until Ptr=2;
  End;

  If Ptr = 1 Then
    PlayerOneScore := CurrentScore
  Else
    PlayerTwoScore := CurrentScore;
  If PlayerOneScore > PlayerTwoScore Then
    Writeln('Player One Wins');
  If PlayerTwoScore > PlayerOneScore Then
    Writeln('Player Two Wins');
  If PlayerOneScore = PlayerTwoScore Then
    Writeln('Tie');
End.
```

Comment: It just crashes and exe closes after I enter a number.

Comment: You have misunderstood JLF's answer, you should replace the '1' in the while statement.

Comment: Rice: I've taken the liberty to reformat your source code. Didn't mean to impose my formatting style on you, just thought it would be more readable that way.

Comment: Did you turn on runtime checks? That is a strong side of Pascal while doing error searching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ptr:=1;
While Ptr < 1 Do

This is your problem. I believe you have to replace 1 with BallsNo.

Comment: It works fine for me though. You might have compiler problems, try compiling it on http://ideone.com/ .
Also, readln can return both integer and string, so that's not the issue. If your program just crashes and doesn't give any message, then it's definately a compiler problem

Comment: It compiles fine but when I run the exe and it asks me how many balls and i enter a number then it crashes.

Comment: @Freddie Rice: Why do you think it crashes? Because of this condition, `Ptr < 1`, it's very likely that your program just finishes never entering the outer `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Change

While Ptr < 1

to

While Ptr > 1

You have a buggy loop further down the algorithm.

-Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

CurrentScore isn't always initialized.
Try inserting "CurrentScore := 0;" after the first "Begin".

Also, how do you know it's crashing?
Maybe it's just not printing anything.
What happens if you add "If PlayerOneScore = PlayerTwoScore Then Writeln('Tie')", just before the "End."?

Comment: Here is the exe with the changes you suggested. Try typing a number and then it outputs tie and it crashes and closes. http://cl.ly/1a1K1K0c3X3M2d043R2N

Comment: Why are you so convinced it is crashing. You state you have no error message; your amendment in response to this answer indicates the program is reaching the end, after accepting a number; and also indicates that the the program is completing and terminating. Is the program not just completing?

Answer (score 0):

Please don't say "it crashes".  It's giving you some sort of error message, what is it?

You've also got a problem that no matter what player one's score is zero.  That won't cause a crash, though.